# ProgressDialog is not showing in my ListActivity's onListItemClick method

Tags: android, listactivity, progressdialog

I have `ListActivity` with `BaseAdapter`. Each time an user clicks an item I clear the adapter and reload new content (it is some sort of tree logic).

Sometimes it takes several seconds that adapter gets new list of items when in `onListItemClick()`. I would like to show some progress bar when entering `onListItemClick()` and hide it when complete.

Why is the progress dialog not showing in my example? I suspect (as I read) the problem would be because the "calculation" is not running in a background thread? If so, can some one please give me an example based on my code?

Here is the code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    catalogAdapter.previousUrl = catalogAdapter.currentUrl;
    RRmlMappingServicesCatalogItem item = catalogAdapter.getItem(position);
    catalogAdapter.currentUrl = item.href;
    //catalogAdapter.mappingServicesCatalog.loadFromRml(new RIoConnectionManagerImpl(this.getApplicationContext()), item.href, null, 120000, 500000);
    loadCatalogFromRml(this.getApplicationContext(), item.href);
    catalogAdapter.clearData();

    if ((catalogAdapter.mappingServicesCatalog.getFlatItems()).length == 0)
    {
        catalogAdapter.mappingServiceContent = new RRmlMappingServiceContent ();
        this.loadContentFromRml(this.getApplicationContext(), item.href);
        //catalogAdapter.mappingServiceContent.loadFromRml(new RIoConnectionManagerImpl(this.getApplicationContext()),item.href, null, 120000, 500000);
        settings = (GlobalSettings) getApplication();
        settings.setMappingServiceContent(catalogAdapter.mappingServiceContent);
        if (catalogAdapter.mappingServiceContent.authentication != null)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(CatalogActivity.this,
                LoginActivity.class));
        }
        else
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(CatalogActivity.this,
                    MapActivity.class));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (RRmlMappingServicesCatalogItem s : catalogAdapter.mappingServicesCatalog.getFlatItems()) {
            catalogAdapter.addItem(s);
        }
        setListAdapter(catalogAdapter);
    }
}

public void loadContentFromRml(Context context, final String url)
{
    final Context myContext = context;
    final String myUrl = url;

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CatalogActivity.this, "",
            "Loading content...", true);

    new Runnable()
    {       
        public void run() 
        {
            catalogAdapter.mappingServiceContent.loadFromRml(new RIoConnectionManagerImpl(myContext),myUrl, null, 120000, 500000);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.run();
}

public void loadCatalogFromRml(Context context, String url)
{
    final Context myContext = context;
    final String myUrl = url;

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CatalogActivity.this, "",
            "Loading catalog...", true);

    new Runnable()
    {       
        public void run() 
        {
            catalogAdapter.mappingServicesCatalog.loadFromRml(new RIoConnectionManagerImpl(myContext), myUrl, null, 120000, 500000);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the busiest line of your code is next:

```
catalogAdapter.mappingServicesCatalog.loadFromRml(...);
```

In order for dialog to show you need to return from function that called `ProgressDialog.show(...)`. That's because an actual processing of this call is done in message loop (this loop called your function in the first place). So in your code you're creating a dialog and marking it to be shown, but never really give it a chance to show itself by calling `.dismiss()` at the end of the same function.

You should use `AsyncTask`. First you need to separate your UI handling code from your `loadFromRml` functionality. Put all time consuming thing in `doInBackground` function of `AsyncTask`, all UI should be either in `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute`.

You could show progress dialog in `onListItemClick` function and dismiss it in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` function. Or, as an alternative, show progress dialog in `AsyncTask.onPreExecute` and hide it in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute`.

There are a lot of examples with `AsyncTask`, one of which is located in [AsycnTask android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Another useful article can be found in android developer resources: [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: Yes you are right. I have tried to implement your solution, but no success (yet). I am still a newbie in android/java...

Comment: Worked perfectly. Code is clean and the solution is awesome. No more using threads directly

Comment: The link to Painless Threading no longer works. Was the link to an article similar to one of these? 
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 0):

I have also face same type of condition in my application but i have resolved it using the given code the code it is.

I have create my progress dialog like this

```
final ProgressDialog dialogMatchList = ProgressDialog
            .show(TennisAppActivity.mContext, "",
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    dialogMatchList.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialogMatchList.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialogMatchList.setCancelable(true);
```

when progress dialog dismiss the blow function is called

```
dialogMatchList.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {

            list.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

        }
    });
```

I hope it is help,

Answer (score 0):

```
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CatalogActivity.this, "",
                "Please wait for few seconds...", true);

    runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
    {


public void run()
  {
      //Do you task here 
       progressDialog.dismiss();


 }
    });
```

If you find it useful please don't forget to mark it as an answer

Best Regards,

~Anup

Comment: i feel like there is something missing here?

Comment: ohh sorry it should be runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
{  public void run(){
  //Do you task here 
   progressDialog.dismiss();}
});

Comment: thanx, but i went with inazaruk's proposal and used AsyncTask. Using threads is messy and i had nothing but trouble.